# Getting wikipedia content page passing its title in Android

Tags: android, json, rest, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm developing an Android app that might use Wikipedia API to retrieve the content of a given page (from its title). I searched a lot in the web but I don't find useful information about the implementation. I read the MediaWiki documentation and I tried to format my requests in json format (example: [request for "mountain" page content](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=Mountain) but the text isn't clear and I don't know how manage the request from my Android application.

So, my question is: how can I getting (clear) wikipedia page content by passing the title page from my application? And how to save the well format content in a String (that will corresponds with a TextView in a second moment)?

Anyone knows a good tutorial or can help me with some snippets?

Thank you very much indeed guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

[action=parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Epic&format=json) or [action=mobileview](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Epic&format=json) or [action=query&prop=extracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=1&titles=All%20your%20base%20are%20belong%20to%20us&format=json), depending on what exactly do you need. Use the [API sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Leeroy%20Jenkins) to interactively experiment with various requests, it has usage examples and shows how to build requests properly.